# Log4j2 creates logs for Ubuntu but not for CentOS

Tags: linux, log4j, log4j2

My program runs as a service in some Linux machines. I have found that on an Ubuntu 16 logging is OK but on CentOS (Linux  local 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 17:04:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) I do not observe log files created in /var/log.

Log4j2 config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="InfoFileAppender"
                     fileName="/var/log/MY.log"
                     filePattern="/var/log/MY.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="TRACE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="InfoFileAppender" level="TRACE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, when I run **sudo service myservice status**, I do see few lines of logs - so they must arrived somewhere else!

I had a guess that maybe journalctl can show me some logs, and used https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/using-journalctl/ to get some journal tailing commands, but withour any result, it replies "No journal files were found."

How I could possibly fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems quite like a permission problem to me. You should give your user write permission of  /var/log.